# Avoiding duplication of directives for different locations?

Tags: nginx

The following rules duplicate the `proxy` directives and I would prefer to only mention them once:

```
location /view/ {
    # Duplicated!
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location /api/ {
    # Duplicated!
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    auth_basic "esqulino Testbetrieb";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/svn/users.conf;
}
```

There are more locations then the ones that I have mentioned here, so specifying the `proxy` directives globally is not an option.

My naive approach was to simply extend the first location with a regex, mention the proxy there and then only specifying the `auth` section for the API:

```
location ~ /(api|view)/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location /api/ {
    auth_basic "esqulino Testbetrieb";
    auth_basic_user_file /srv/svn/users.conf;
}
```

But for some reason this does not trigger the authentication at all.

How could I mention the `proxy` (or actually any) directives only once for a set of locations and still "overload" some more specific locations with additional directives like `auth_basic`?

Comment: @downvoter Would you care to explain? If there is anything unclear I am more then happy to provide additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is explained in the nginx documentation. only one of those locations is used, they are not merged together:

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks
>   locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among
>   them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and
>   remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of
>   their appearance in the configuration file. The search of regular
>   expressions terminates on the first match, and the corresponding
>   configuration is used. If no match with a regular expression is found
>   then the configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is
>   used.
>   (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)

as an alternative you could use an `include` and move the duplicated config lines to another file - for example below `/etc/nginx/snippets/`

**EDIT** The idea with nested locations from our comments:

Though I am not sure this is 100% correct as I did not test it, yet, try something like this:

```
location ~ /(view|api) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    location /api/ {
        auth_basic "esqulino Testbetrieb";
        auth_basic_user_file /srv/svn/users.conf;
    }
}
```

Another option might be to use `if ($uri ~ ^/api)` within the regex-location

Comment: This perfectly expains *why* this doesn't work, but I am not quite comfortable with using another file. Is there a possibility to define some kind of constant and refer to that instead of putting these two lines in a new file?

Comment: The very same documentation mentions that one could nest locations. Though I haven't used this feature, yet.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for, thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.